# Where am i getting this bus error?

Tags: c, string, compiler-errors

When I compile this code I experience a bus error and I don't understand what I'm doing to cause this. I read up what a bus error entails and I still don't quite see my problem. This code should reproduce the behaviour of the strcpy() function in the string.h library.

```css
#include <unistd.h>

void ft_putstr(char *str)
{
 while (*str)
  write(1, str++, 1);
}

char *ft_strcpy(char *dest, char *src)
{
 int index;

 index = 0;
 while (src[index] != '\0')
 {
  dest[index] = src[index];
  index++;
 }
 dest[index] = '\0';
 return (dest);
}

int main(void)
{
 char *str1, *str2, *cpy;

 str1 = "Cameron";
 str2 = "Why you no work?";
 cpy = ft_strcpy(str1, str2);
 ft_putstr(cpy);
 return (0);
}
```

Comment: string literals are not writable.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *name = "string";
```

creates a **string literal** in the memory, that can't be later rewritten.
Use malloc and your function instead of this initialization like this.

Comment: How do I solve this problem without malloc, the course that I am doing requires that I solve this without being able to malloc.

Comment: use ordinary array then, char array[50];